# Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the last version of Android Studio and my project now have error: 'Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()''. I can't fix it.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: not possible with this build.gradle file ... you have already changed `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled` ... please share source of parent(the one from parent directory) `build.gradle` ... also check other modules build.gradle files

Comment: Whats your class path ??? classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle: